# Flutter Deep Link with web view implementation

Tags: flutter, webview, deep-linking

I am trying to implement Deep Link in my Flutter Application.

The Application contains a web view(e-commerce web) and I want to search for specific products on that web view when any external link gets chicked.

I am attaching the code of Flutter with Android Menifest

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uni_links/uni_links.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyWebView(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
    _MyWebViewState createState() => _MyWebViewState();
}

class _MyWebViewState extends State<MyWebView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initUniLinks(context);
  }
  late WebViewController _webViewController;
  String uuu = 'https://url';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebView'),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: uuu,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _webViewController = webViewController;
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> initUniLinks(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      // Get the initial deep link
      final initialLink = await getInitialLink();

      // Handle the initial deep link if it exists
      _handleLink(initialLink, context);

      // Listen for incoming deep links
      linkStream.listen((String? link) {
        _handleLink(link, context);
      }, onError: (error) {});
    } catch (error) {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }

  void _handleLink(String? link, BuildContext context) async {
    if (link != null) {
      final Uri deepLink = Uri.parse(link);
      final String route = deepLink.pathSegments[0];

      if (route != 'cycl') {
        print("ok");
        uuu = 'https://url/search?q=cycle';
        await _webViewController.loadUrl(uuu);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <application
        android:label="shopify_testing"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|
                                    keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|
                                    layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
              the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
              while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
              to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="url"
                  />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
              This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have tried to implement but when i click on any external link i m redirect to website